# android RecyclerView adapter notify item removed at position with viewModel

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have a `RecyclerView` with it's `viewModel` which has a list of items.
How to detect item removed at position and call `myAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)`
?
ps: `RecyclerView` has it's own `viewModel` an I have to pass new list to it's viewModel and then call `notifyItemRemoved(position)` from my `fragment`

Comment: Do you have custom adapter for the RecyclerView? If so, please provide the code of it.

Comment: Please post your code so that we can help

Answer (score 0):

i think i use LiveData with mvvm that use observe design pattern to observe when data change

if your repository get data again from server and bind it to view to added to recyclerview adapter using function say called setData(List data)
in adapter will compare two list to find deleted or added item index

if you use repository to delete one item please send index to main view and save it in int variable